# Branch deeplink opens Appstore instead of App even though app is already installed

Tags: ios, deep-linking, branch.io

Our users gets deeplink to our app in mail, but whenever user clicks on the deeplink in mail, user is redirected to App store even though app is installed in device and while coming from app store deep link gets lost. This is happening for some users and for others deeplink just works fine.

I tried to get in contact with Branch support but didn't get any reply yet.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-universal-links) page?

Comment: @omerfarukozturk yes I did, setup is correct as explained in the link. Problem is it works for some users and for some it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be either because of the following issues:

1. Universal Emails are not enabled for your app,
2. AASA files not getting downloaded for certain devices.

Universal emails need to be enabled for your app in order for deep-linking to work properly for your email marketing campaigns.

There is an ongoing issue with Apple post iOS versions 11.x+ where the AASA files do not get downloaded for certain devices, thus causing the universal links to fail. You can refer to our doc here in order to understand on how to troubleshoot for the same. : https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/ios-troubleshooting#section-validate-if-aasa-file-successfully-downloaded

I am sorry to hear that you have faced certain inconvenience while reaching out to Branch support. If you could supply the case number, we will check on providing you with the best possible solution to your queries.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps someone:
In my Branch.io configuration, i had for ios "Enable Universal Links" activated, but i didnt have it populated. I did have "I have an iOS app" checked and configured.  For some reason my mistake led to always opening app store instead of local app.  User error over here but hopefully helps someone some day